# Making IMAPMessage Parcelable

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, marshalling, unmarshalling

What is the procedure to make JavaMail Message Parcelable as by default Message can not be serialized? How to achieve the serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply "serialize" the message by writing it to a stream (or string) and then parsing it back again to "deserialize" it?